# how to read data from python serial.readline() data into string

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Program details:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyS0', 
baudrate = 9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=1
)
counter=0

def Off():
    print('17')

def Go():
    print('18')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commands = {15:Go, 14:Off}

    try:
        ser.write(str.encode('allon'))

        while True:
            x=ser.readline()
            print(x)
            commands[x]()

    finally:
           print("ok")
```

## Heading

and in the output, I am getting

```
b'On\r\n'
b''
b'Ogg\r\n'
b''
b''
b'Off\r\n'
b'On\r\n'
```

But I want something like x = 14 as a string
so that I can pass this value in command x

here I am getting error..................

Comment: bad bad baaaaad indentation. Please fix it before someone gets their eyes burned

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0', 
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
counter=0

def ON():  # added ON
    print('15')

def Off():
    print('17')

def Go():
    print('18')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commands = {b'Go': Go, b'ON': On, b'Off': Off}  # changed commands dictionary

    try:
        ser.write(str.encode('allon'))

        while True:
            x = ser.readline().strip()  # added strip (removing \r\n)
            print(x)  # remove this line if you do not want all input to be printed
            if x in commands:  # added condition
                commands[x]()

    finally:
           print("ok")
```

Comment: Solutions:               x = ser.readline()
                x=(x.decode('utf-8'))
                x= x.split("\r")
                print(x[0])

Comment: Hi Cloudomation   thanks for quick reply 
             x=ser.readline()
            print(x)                                                                           print something like >>b'ON\r\n'
                               >>b'Off\r\n'

Comment: @ Cloudomation Now I am Getting Hex Code                                             --                                          b'\xfd'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x1b'
b''

Comment: @BUBAINAYAK it seems the serial console receives these data. Are you typing into the console? What is the output when you type `ON` ? If you do not want all input to be printed just remove the line `print(x)`